# How to inject String property in a spring bean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

We inject simple property with configuration as shown below :

```
<bean id="myService" class="com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyServiceImpl">
    <property name="myProp" value=""/>
</bean>
```

How would you do it with annotations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `@Value` annotation. It supports SpEL as well, which means you can load a properties file and have `@Value("${someConfigurationProperty}")`